# Find Samba Mount location on OS X

Tags: macos, samba, terminal.app

If I connect to a Samba Share through the 'Connect to Server' dialogue in the finder in OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.2), I can use this in the finder to drag/drop files etc etc. But if I want to access this share from the terminal, whereabouts should I look? I guessed it may be in /share or something similar, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OS X, everything mounted via the GUI (and mostly everything you didn't mount yourself via the command line) is available under `/Volumes`.

This can be checked with the `mount` command. Here's an example where I mounted one SMB and two AFP shares—the last three lines:

```
$ mount
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
localhost:/FMN48UV69AlSIREfdWJEiA on /Volumes/MobileBackups (mtmfs, nosuid, read-only, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /Volumes/Data (hfs, local, journaled)
/dev/disk1s5 on /Volumes/TimeMachine (hfs, local, journaled)
//GUEST:@meredith.local/music on /Volumes/music (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, noowners, mounted by werner)
//;AUTH=No%20User%20Authent@Meredith._afpovertcp._tcp.local/movies on /Volumes/movies (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by werner)
//;AUTH=No%20User%20Authent@Meredith._afpovertcp._tcp.local/software on /Volumes/software (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by werner)
```

To narrow down your `mount` output to SMB shares only, use `mount | grep smb`:

```
//GUEST:@meredith.local/music on /Volumes/music (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, noowners, mounted by werner)
```